# How to check the number of command-line arguments?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, io, command-line-arguments

I have a project in Haskell Language and I am not very experienced in this technology.

My program must take 5 command-line arguments (binary included), it should be like the following line :

```
./my_program --a 30 --b 20
```

How can I check the number of arguments (return an error if `arguments != 5`)?

I know the `getargs` function but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of how you can use [`getArgs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs):

```
module Main where

import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  if length args == 5
    then putStrLn "You gave me 5 args!"
    else putStrLn "You didn't give me 5 args!"
```

**Edit:** It was `length args`, not `args`, thanks.

**Edit:** But note that `getArgs` on `./my_program --a 30 --b 20` will, unlike in C, not mention `./my_program` as part of the arguments. If you want the program name it's [`getProgName`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getProgName). Otherwise, the right number is probably 4. For the sake of working with the IO monad, you could extend the program to print out the name of the executable:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs, ...)

main = IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  name <- ...

  putStrLn ("Program: " <> show name)
  if length args == 4
    ...
```

---

But what you appear to be going for is argument parsing, not just counting.

You could use [`optparse-generic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-generic) to auto-generate an argument parser based on a datatype.

There is an example in the documentation for [`Options.Generic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-generic-1.4.3/docs/Options-Generic.html) that I turned into a template project [here](https://github.com/sshine/hello), with the important parts mentioned below for posterity:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO)
import Options.Generic

data Config w = Config
  { bleeps :: w ::: Int <?> "Number of bleeps"
  , bloops :: w ::: Int <?> "Number of bloops"
  } deriving (Generic)

instance ParseRecord (Config Wrapped)
deriving instance Show (Config Unwrapped)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  config <- getConfig
  putStrLn $
    "I got " <> show (bleeps config) <> " bleeps, and "
             <> show (bloops config) <> " bloops."

getConfig :: IO (Config Unwrapped)
getConfig = unwrapRecord "Hello"
```

If you replace `bleeps` and `bloops` with `a` and `b`, you can run the program with e.g.

```
$ stack run -- --a 30 --b 20
```